# Creating / downloading a .html file with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Chrome extension. So far my code takes elements of a webpage and creates HTML markup (loaded in a string in Javascript).

My extension leads in a button

```
$(".column1").prepend('<div class="actions" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;"><button id="edmMaker">Make an EDM!</a></div>')
$('#edmMaker').click(function(){
    var html = "<body><section><h1>Here is some HTML text</h1></section><div><p>Here's some more</p></div></body>"
    // create a .html file and download it to the user's desktop
});
```

In Node.JS I would just write a `.html` file to the local disk, but I can't quite figure out how this works in Chrome Extension world.

How can I do this?

Sub-question: Is there any way to tabify the HTML that is being output? The actual code I'm outputting is an HTML email template, and Javascript will only let me load in a string without line breaks and tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method I wrote that leverages [HTML5's download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to download a file:

```
var saveHTML = function(fileName, html){
    //  Escape HTML

    var el = document.createElement("dummy");
    el.innerText = html;

    var escapedHTML = el.innerHTML;

    //  Use dummy <a /> tag to save

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = fileName;
    link.href = "data:text/plain,"+escapedHTML;

    link.click(); // trigger click/download
};

saveHTML("myHTML.html", "<html></html>");
```

**Check it out in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7jozjjs/).**

If you're not looking to save the file, you can just use [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

**EDIT:**

As @Xan pointed out below, the [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API exists as well which may be of some use, specifically [`chrome.downloads.download()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) method.

---

As for multiline strings with tabs/spaces/newlines, there's 3 ways:

**1.)** Manually, using newlines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`)

```
"<body>\n\t<section>\n\t\t<h1>Here is some HTML text</h1>\n\t</section>\n\t<div>\n\t\t<p>Here's some more</p>\n\t</div>\n</body>"
```

Which comes out to:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Here is some HTML text</h1>
    </section>
    <div>
        <p>Here's some more</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**2.)** Using JavaScript's multi-line string support, which requires that you insert a backslash at the end of a line:

```
var html = "<body>\
    <section>\
        <h1>Here is some HTML text</h1>\
    </section>\
    <div>\
        <p>Here's some more</p>\
    </div>\
</body>";
```

**3.)** `Array.join`:

```
var html = [
    "<body>",
    "   <section>",
    "       <h1>Here is some HTML text</h1>",
    "   </section>",
    "   <div>",
    "       <p>Here's some more</p>",
    "   </div>",
    "</body>"
].join("\n");
```

Comment: \*cough\* [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) \*cough\*

Comment: @Xan actually, it looks like `chrome.downloads.download` would work much the same way as my function above. I'll include it anyway. I also can't tell it it would accept a data URI (probably)

Comment: Perfect! Had no idea Javascript had that multi-line string support, that's gonna be a lifesaver in future projects. Thanks for your very detailed response!

Comment: @Jascination Avoid JavaScript multiline string because they fail if there is a space after one of the backslashes. That's essentially an invisible bug in when you look at it in your editor.

Comment: This answer works better than `chrome.downloads` for me, `chrome.downloads` replaces .html with .txt in my filename, at least in vivaldi. Note that a better way to do it is to use base64 encoding: `link.href = "data:text/html;base64,"+btoa(html)`